# Statement of maximum modulus principle and question

Tags: complex-analysis

**Question 1**

My book (Complex Variables by Churchill) states

> If a function $f$ is analytic and not constant in a given domain $D$, the $|f(z)|$ has no maximum value in $D$. that is, there is no point $z_0$ in the domain such that $|f(z)| \leq |f(z_0)|$ for all points $z$ in it.

I believe this statement of the theorem is wrong or insufficient because it does not state that $D$ is a connected open subset of $\mathbb{C}$. Am I right or is the statement of the theorem correct?

Further into the chapter, the book even states

> If a function $f$ that is analytic at each point in the interior of a closed bounded region $R$ is also continuous throughout $R$, then the modulus $|f(z)|$ has a maximum value somewhere in $R$.

so it seems to have left out the fact that $D$ must be open in the statement of the theorem.

Comment: How does it define *domain*? [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_%28mathematical_analysis%29) says *"In mathematical analysis, a domain is any connected open subset of a finite-dimensional vector space"*.

Comment: I think domains are usually defined to be connected (you might have to check in your particular text). As for the second theorem, this is just the extreme value theorem.

Comment: Usually a domain is a connected open set. With respect to the second question, a closed bounded region is compact. So $|f(z)|$ attains a maximum because of continuity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second statement is just implied by continuity of the function on a compact set. Moreover, in complex analysis, a domain is by definition a connected open subset of the complex numbers.

Comment: I did not realize that was the implied definition of a domain. Is there a reason for why a connected open subset is defined as a domain and not a closed subset?

Comment: In the real-variable, you generally define differentiability of a function in an open interval (unless you want to consider left and right derivatives). In the complex setting, it is also simple to consider subsets with no boundary.

What definition will you give for a holomorphic function on the closed unit ball ? There are at least two possibilities: a continuous function that is holomorphic in the open unit ball OR a function that is the restriction of a holomorphic function on an open neighborhood of the closed unit ball.

Comment: And this is generally the second possibility that is used...